# От сервера получено TLS оповещение: Handshake failed (40)

Tags: tls

Пытаюсь использовать FTP на моем сайте. Я удостоверился, что мой IP-адрес не заблокирован, и я использую правильные порты, но я все еще получаю этот журнал ошибок:

> Ошибка:    От сервера получено TLS оповещение: Handshake failed (40)
>   Ошибка:    Невозможно подключиться к серверу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне помогло подключение через протокол SFTP

Answer (score 2):

Везде пишут, что причиной тому то, что сервер и клиент не имеют общих протоколов шифрования. И скорее всего сервер хочет rc4, которій біл отключен в FileZilla. Варианты решения

- отключить шифрование - в настройах, на вкладке общее, выбрать "использовать только plain  auth" [SO](https://superuser.com/questions/874981/recieved-tls-alert-from-the-server-handshake-failed-40)
- попробовать обновить сервер/посмотреть в его конфиги
- попробовать другой клиент (а может просто старую версию той же FileZilla).

Comment: Спасибо большое, первый пункт использывал. Через менеджер сайтов  вибрал Использовать обычный FTP (небезопасно)

Comment: > Спасибо большое, первый пункт использывал. Через менеджер сайтов
> вибрал Использовать обычный FTP (небезопасно)
Спасибо это помогло

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже выбрал "Использовать обычный FTP (небезопасно)" и все заработало!